# Proxy rules doesn't get applied while connecting through Netty

Tags: java, http, proxy, netty

It is observed that some rules applied thorough a proxy is not supported by Netty because of the HTTP CONNECT request is sent initially.

- Proxy - Squid
- Rule - Block destination URL http://example.com/foo/bar/1

As an example when we setup the above proxy with the given rules and send a GET request to http://example.com/foo/bar/1, it is expected to block http://example.com/foo/bar/1 but allow http://example.com/foo/bar/2

But the actual behavior is that both URLs are allowed and 200 OK responses are returned. But the expected behavior can be seen by Mozilla Firefox for the same proxy with same set of rules.

Netty version - 4.1.19.Final

Java version  - 1.8.0_171

Answer (score 0):

This issue gives out the explanation.

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7930